# Function maybe written wrong, doesn't toggle image

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, getelementbyid

This code is supposed to toggle between the "like" and "unlike" images, except it doesn't. Can anybody tell me what i wrote wrong. And yes i am new to javascript.

```
<script>
        function imgclick(){
        var like = "like.png",
            unlike = "unlike.png";
        var liked = document.getElemendById("liked");

        liked.src = (liked.src === unlike)? like : unlike;
        }
</script>
    <img src="unlike.png" id="liked" width="200" height="200" onclick="imgclick();">
```

Comment: Are there any errors in DevTools? (`F12`)

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo in the following line:

```
var liked = document.getElemendById("liked");
```

You put `getElemendById` when it should be `getElementById`:

```
var liked = document.getElementById("liked");
```

Comment: yes i caught up on that, but it still didnt work. i changed:                                       
  `liked.src = (liked.src === unlike)? like : unlike;`                                                           to                                                                                                                         
  `liked.src = (liked.src === like)? unlike : like;`                                                            
and it would just change one way, not the other.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to JS I just want to recommend to you to use relative paths every time you can, because it is going to save you a headache in the future.

It goes like this: `var like = "./like.png"`